# phalcon url routing

Tags: phalcon

Есть например запрос к моему сайту по `url: www.site.ru/api/dso?prm=MSK`
Есть роут:

```
$router->add("/api/dso", array(
'namespace' => 'Api',
'controller' => 'main',
'action' => 'dso',
));
```

Вопрос: Как мне перевести,например, `url : www.site.ru/api/**D**so?prm=MSK` в `lowercase`, чтобы роутер отработал правильно т.е. обратился к указанному контроллеру и методу независимо от регистра?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
$router->add("/api/**D**so?prm=".mb_strtolower{param}), array(
'namespace' => 'Api',
'controller' => 'main',
'action' => 'dso',
));
```

Или:

```
$router->add(mb_strtolower("/api/**D**so?prm={param}), array(
'namespace' => 'Api',
'controller' => 'main',
'action' => 'dso',
));
```